# i'm unable to perform skipFirstRows parameter while reading excel in pyspark - python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-excel

**Note: we should not use pandas.read_excel() while reading excel in my case. we only** **need to use spark-excel jar installed in our cluster.**

my main point is. we have skip few lines in the excel sheet while reading the file by using any logic or any parameter like ("skipFirstRows", "[int value]")

```
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
               .option("header", "true")\
               .option("inferSchema", "true")\
               .option("skipFirstRows","1")\ 
               .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")\
               .load("dbfs:/FileStore/filename.xlsx")
df
```

Even after using this parameter **.option("skipFirstRows","1")** the line was not getting skipped while reading. it's raise error in the first line itself.

**ERROR:**
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a** **NUMERIC formula cell**

**My excel has one numeric value in the first row in the 6th or 7th cell**
**and from the second line of my excel the actual header starts.**

**so i have to skip that first line.**

**Excel sample :**

[image]

please help me to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: what error it raise? You should show it in question (not in comments)

Comment: @furas i've added the error msg and a sample excel file format to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skipFirstRows` was [deprecated](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0110) in favor of more generic [dataAddress](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#data-addresses) option. For skipping rows in your example, try:

```py
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
       .option("dataAddress","A2")
       .load("dbfs:/FileStore/filename.xlsx")
```

Comment: can anyone tell me how to skip rows dynamically until header row is identified in pyspark ??
Note:  either the file is in xlsx or csv

Comment: @GouthamBoine, you know I haven't seen such examples but I imagine how that's a totally fine common case. That is, it sounds like a good question, and the answer to this might greatly benefit the community, don't limit with the comments section box.

Comment: i've posted this as another question just now. let's see if anyone can help us.

link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711636/how-can-we-skip-lines-automatically-in-excel-and-csv-file-until-header-row-is-fo