# How can we skip lines automatically in excel and csv file until header row is found in python (pyspark)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Can we make the code to skip unnecessary lines until the header row is found in excel and csv files by using python (any module)

Note : if anyone can help me in doing that in pyspark would be appreciated

**Example :**
[image]

**In the above sample excel we need to skip the first 3 rows automatically and start reading** **the file from 4th line starting with "G/L" which is the main header line of the document.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to use Pandas to read the CSV and XLSX files as it has the easiest interface and later on convert it to PySpark. I also added two alternatives that you can try out depending on your setup and preferences.

**Direct Pandas**

```py
pandas_df = pd.read_excel('path/file.xlsx', sheet_name='Table 1', skiprows=3)
```

`skiprows=3` defines, how many lines shall be skipped before Pandas starts to read the file.
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

**PySpark**

If you want to use PySpark directly, you'll need to install two libraries on your cluster:

- `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.7` (from Maven)
- `xlrd` (from PyPI)

You can use then `spark.read` as follows:

```py
spark_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("dataAddress", "'Table 1'!A4") \
    .load(filePath)
```

Here can you tell spark to start in field `A4` in the option `dataAddress`.

**PySpark over Pandas**

Using the simple interface but directly converting to PySpark is also possible since Pyspark 3.2.0. You can use the syntax as follows:

```py
spark_df = spark.pandas.read_excel('path/file.xlsx', sheet_name='Table 1', skiprows=3)
```

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: yes i agree with your answer but it is in static way right  ??. If i have 3 excels as input for my program and in each excel ( skiprows = n ) count may differ. we need to write the logic so that it automatically skips the rows until header line

Comment: how do you define the header line? Do you know for each file what n is?

Comment: Just want to mention that I've posted a suggestion at Microsoft to also add a `SkpiLines` option to the default Data Text driver, I'd appreciate an upvote here https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8f133bc7-1f8c-ed11-a81b-000d3ae5ae95 which could make processing Excel and csv files easier